# Using ContentResolver and Regex to get music from specific folder

Tags: android, regex, android-contentresolver

I am currently trying to retrieve music files within a specific folder from the **ContentResolver**. I only want the files in that folder, not from a subfolder. I achieved to get these files by doing this:

```
String pattern = f.getAbsolutePath() + "/[^/]*"; // f is the folder where I want to search
ArrayList<TrackInfo> retVal = new ArrayList<TrackInfo>();
Cursor mCursor = null;

String selection = MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_MUSIC + " != 0 AND " + DATA + " LIKE '" + f.getAbsolutePath() + "/%'";

Uri contentUri = Media.getContentUriForPath(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath());
String projection[] = new String[]{DATA};

mCursor = context.getContentResolver().query(contentUri, projection, selection, null, DATA);

String data, fileName[];
while(mCursor.moveToNext()){

    data = mCursor.getString(0);        
    if(data.matches(pattern)){
        fileName = data.split("/");

        retVal.add(new TrackInfo(fileName[fileName.length-1], null, data, null, -1, R.drawable.notes, false));
    }           
}

mCursor.close();
```

This worked out for most cases. But now I seem to have an issue with my pattern. The problem is that if the pattern contains parentheses, `data.matches(pattern)` always returns false. Examples I tried were:

```
String pattern1 = "/mnt/somepath/folder(with-parentheses)/[^/]*";
String pattern2 = "/mnt/somepath/folder/[^/]*";

String string1 = "/mnt/somepath/folder(with-parentheses)/test1";
String string2 = "/mnt/somepath/folder/test2";

System.out.println("\"" + string1 + "\"" + ".matches(\"" + pattern1 + "\") = " + string1.matches(pattern1));
System.out.println("\"" + string2 + "\".matches(\"" + pattern2 + "\") = " + string2.matches(pattern2));
```

The output was:

```
"/mnt/somepath/folder(with-parentheses)/test1*".matches("/mnt/somepath/folder(with-parentheses)/[^/]*") = false
"/mnt/somepath/folder/test2".matches("/mnt/somepath/folder/[^/]*") = true
```

My question now is:
Is there a more effective way to get all music files within a folder? - I have already tried to check every file within a folder for a pattern (containing the supported media formats I found [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html#core)). The problem with that approach is that these formats are only *Core Media Formats* - the phone may support more than that.
And why is my pattern not working?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: You need to escape the `()`, i.e. `\(\)`, since `()` are special characters in regex.

Comment: Thanks, that worked. If you put it in an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`(`, `)` (and many others such as `+`,`*`,`[`,`]`, `.`) are special characters in regex. Therefore, it is necessary to escape them, i.e. `\(`, `\)` in order to specify the literal character.

However, in this case, since you obtain the pattern by concatenating `f.getAbsolutePath()`, it is **strongly** recommended that you use [`Pattern.quote(String)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#quote%28java.lang.String%29) to make all characters in `f.getAbsolutePath()` literal. It will make sure none of the character are interpreted as special character in regex.

```
String pattern = Pattern.quote(f.getAbsolutePath()) + "/[^/]*";
```

(When you print out the `pattern` after applying `Pattern.quote`, you may notice that it adds `\Q` and `\E` to the original string. It is the way to escape all characters in a long string, supported by Java regex and several other regex flavors).